# IIS can read Program Files folder contents

Tags: iis, permissions, ntfs

I'm creating a website in IIS 8.5. My webroot is E:\wwwroot\MySite, I give Full Permissions to TestUser user (which defined in system, member of WebUser group and configured to use in IIS Application Pool Identity, also set Anonymous user identity to Application pool identity [default is IUSR])

I have removed the Users group access on whole E drive, and its inherited correctly by my wwwroot and MySite folders.

When I try to access paths outside my web directory using simple Classic ASP `Scripting.FileSystemObject`, I can read successfully.

This way I can access, for example Program Files directory, and its contents. Many applications save its settings in that folder, so it is dangerous.

I tried to add Deny Full Control for my WebUser group on whole C drive but it seems I can't modify Program Files or Windows directory permissions.

What is the correct way to configure a system to accomplish each web site can only see its root directory (not Windows, Program Files etc. and other website directories)?

Comment: Are you sure you are using full IIS instead of IIS Express?

Comment: @LexLi Yes, I'm using IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2.